# Iterating over list of nested dictionaries with different fields

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to get one set with all possible infos existing in a list of nested dictionaries `data`:

```
data = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'info': [
                        {
                            "id": 999,
                            "name": 'steering wheel problems'
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 99,
                            "name": None
                        }
            ],
            'owner':
                        {
                            "id": 999,
                            "name": 'alice'
                        },
            "type":
                        {
                            "value": 987,
                            "id": 129,
                            "name": 'A',
                            "type": 'zaz'
                        }
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'info':[
                {
                    "id": 989,
                    "name": 'gearbox problems'
                },
                {
                    "id": 98,
                    "name": 'broken engine'
                },
                {
                    "id": 97,
                    "name": 'throttle problems'
                }
            ],
            'owner':
                        {
                            "id": 999,
                            "name": 'alice'
                        },
            "type":
                {
                    "value": 765,
                    "id": 121,
                    "name": 'B',
                    "type": 'zbz'
                }
        },
        {
            'id': 3,
            'info':
                {

                },
            'owner':
                        {
                            "id": 989,
                            "name": 'deborah'
                        },
            "type":
                {
                    "value": 432,
                    "id": 123,
                    "name": 'B',
                    "type": 'zcz'
                }
        },
        {
            'id': 4,
            'info':
                {
                    "id": 33,
                    "name": 'broken engine'
                },
            'owner':
                        {
                            "id": 969,
                            "name": 'luke'
                        },
            "type":
                {
                    "value": 543,
                    "id": 412,
                    "name": 'C',
                    "type": 'zdz'
                }
        },
        {
            'id': 5,
            'info':
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "name": 'broken engine'
                },
            'owner':
                        {
                            "id": 979,
                            "name": 'joe'
                        },
            "type":
                {
                    "value": 318,
                    "id": 192,
                    "name": 'B',
                    "type": 'ziz'
                }
        }
]
```

I expect something like this: `infos = ['steering wheel problems', 'gearbox problems', 'broken engine', 'throttle problems', None]` but I'm running into problems with my code:

```
for d in data:
    infos = []
    for i in d['info']:
        j = i['name']
        infos.append(j)
```

```
j = i['name']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `d['info']` does not always have the same structure. Sometimes it's a list of dictionaries, sometimes it's just a dictionary. In the latter case you will get that error.

Comment: What about the last two "broken engine"s. You don't want them?

Comment: What I expect is rather a set of unique items that exist in data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
infos = {
    i.get("name") for d in data for i in 
                  (d["info"] if isinstance(d["info"], list) else [d["info"]])
}
# {None, 'gearbox problems', 'broken engine', 'throttle problems', 'steering wheel problems'}
```

and take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

Built on your attempt:

```py
info_set = set()
for d in data:
    if type(d['info']) == dict and 'name' in d['info'].keys():
            info_set.add(d['info']['name'])
    else:
        for elt in d['info']:
            if type(elt) == dict and 'name' in elt.keys():
                info_set.add(elt['name'])
print(info_set)
```

Answer (score 1):

your corrected code may look like this :

```
infos = []
for d in data:
    if (type(d["info"]) is list) and (len(d["info"]) > 0):
        for i in d['info']:
            if "name" in i:
                j = i['name']
                infos.append(j)
    elif ("name" in d["info"]) and (type(d["info"]) is dict):
        infos.append(d["info"]["name"])
    else:
        continue
infos = set(infos)
```

Although, answer given by @schwobaseggl is more compact.

Answer (score 0):

info=[]
for dicto in data:

```
li=dicto['info']

for l in li:
    if l =={}:
        continue  

    try:
       info.append( l['name'])
    except: 
        print("")
```

print(info)**hope this might fix it**